# Include defined PHP variable in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am not too familiar with Javascript so I was hoping I could get a little advice on how to include a PHP variable within javascript.

I have written a PHP code to set a variable waiting time for a hyperlink depending on server load.

A snippet of the PHP code is:

```
// set wait level
if($count_user_online <= "99") {
    $wait_level="0";
}
else if($count_user_online >= "100" && $count_user_online < "199") {
    $wait_level="60";
}
else if($count_user_online >= "200" && $count_user_online < "299") {
    $wait_level="120";
}
else if($count_user_online >= "300" && $count_user_online < "399") {
    $wait_level="180";
}
else if($count_user_online >= "400" && $count_user_online < "499") {
    $wait_level="240";
}
else if($count_user_online >= "500") {
    $wait_level="300";
}
```

I am trying to echo $wait_level within the Javascript. I have done it the HTML method below, but obviously this isn't correct. Can anybody suggest a functional approach?

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=function() {
document.getElementById('redirect').style.display = 'none';
function countdown() {
if ( typeof countdown.counter == 'undefined' ) {
   countdown.counter = <?php echo $wait_level ?>; // seconds
   }
if(countdown.counter >= 0) {
   document.getElementById('count').innerHTML = countdown.counter--;
   setTimeout(countdown, 1000);
   }
else {
   document.getElementById('redirect').style.display = '';
   }
}
countdown();
};
</script>

</head>
<body>
<h2>You can can access the link in <span id="count"></span> seconds <a id="redirect" href="http://google.com/">Google</a></h2>
</body>
</html>
```

I am aware the javascript I am using will allow you to easily view the hyperlink by viewing the source, but this isn't the final javascript code I will be using so there is no need to worry about that.

The script will only be used for 1 day on a private server so does not need to be clean, just functional.

Any help is really very much appreciated!

Comment: Unrelated to your issue, but you could replace that whole if / else block with a single line: `$wait_level = (floor($count_user_online / 100) * 60) + '';`

Comment: Doesn't seem like there should be a problem. Can you add the error or the output to the problem description?

Comment: Try and get away from using <?php ?> inside html and javascript

Comment: Check my update answer, this is the method i'd usually go with -> http://stackoverflow.com/a/30802303/3296661

Comment: Hi Chris, what is wrong with using <?php ?> inside html? I've seen this is very wide spread? Is there a down side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I'd go about getting PHP to JavaScript would be using Ajax

Ajax you'll be able to load data from your server by using a HTTP Post request, the good thing about using Ajax is that you can send parameters with the HTTP request. E.g. If you wanted to send a parameter which would be used for a DB query. Then you'd be able to do so and you'd be able to return the data from that DB query.

I'm not saying it's bad practise to use PHP inside JavaScript because it's perfectly acceptable, but it can be very risky - you're generating parts of the JS on-the-fly, which means you have to generate VALID JS code, or the whole code block will be killed by a syntax error.

e.g.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var lastName = '<?php echo $lastName ?>';
</script>
```

and `$lastName` happens to be O'Neil, you've now introduced a syntax error, because the generated code will be:

```
var lastName = 'O'Neil';
                --- string with contents O
                   --- unknown/undefined variable Neil
                     -- string followed by variable, but no operator present.
                        --- start of a new unterminated string containing a ';'
```

So if you was going to carry on with inserting raw PHP-based data into a JS variable, you basically MUST use json_encode(), which guarantees that the generated JS data is syntactically valid JS code

**My method getting PHP data**

**Server side - Test1.php**

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['usersOnline']))
{


$count_user_online = $_POST['usersOnline'];

switch ($count_user_online) {
    case  ($count_user_online <= "99"):
            $wait_level = "0";
        break;

    case  ($count_user_online >= "100" && $count_user_online < "199"):
            $wait_level = "1";
        break;

    case  ($count_user_online >= "200" && $count_user_online < "299"):
            $wait_level = "2";
        break;
}

echo $wait_level;

}

?>
```

**HTML Side - Test.php**

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">     </script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    sendUserCount("200");
    document.getElementById('redirect').style.display = 'none';
});

function countdown(count) {
     if ( typeof countdown.counter == 'undefined' ) {
        countdown.counter = count; // seconds
     }

     if(countdown.counter >= 0) {
        document.getElementById('count').innerHTML = countdown.counter--;
        setTimeout(countdown, 1000);
     }
     else {
        document.getElementById('redirect').style.display = '';
     }
  }

  function sendUserCount(userCount)
  {
     var url = document.location.href;
     $.post("test1.php",
     {
        usersOnline: userCount
     })

     .success(function (data)
     {
        console.log(data);
        countdown(data);
     });
   }

</script>

</head>
<body>
  <h2>You can can access the link in <span id="count"></span> seconds <a id="redirect" href="http://google.com/">Google</a></h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Cerbrus Check my updated answer, try creating test.php like I did and see if it works for you

Comment: I'm not saying the code doesn't work. I'm just saying that this doesn't answer the OP's question.

Comment: I'm not the one that posted the question.

Comment: @Cerbrus Sorry about that, wrong comment. Suppose to put it one the main Question :) - However is the answer better? than "Your code works for me"?

Comment: It is, yes. However, I'd try to explain a thing or 2 about the ajax call you've added, and why php in htm / js is supposed to be bad.

Comment: @Cerbrus That should do it :) That should explain to him

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if there is a better way of doing it, but I have managed to make it work with the following code:

```
<html>
<head>

<div id="dom-target" style="visibility: hidden">
<?php 
    echo htmlspecialchars($wait_level); 
?>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var div = document.getElementById("dom-target");
var myData = div.textContent;
window.onload=function() {
document.getElementById('redirect').style.display = 'none';
function countdown() {
if ( typeof countdown.counter == 'undefined' ) {
   countdown.counter = myData; // seconds
   }
if(countdown.counter >= 0) {
   document.getElementById('count').innerHTML = countdown.counter--;
   setTimeout(countdown, 1000);
   }
else {
   document.getElementById('redirect').style.display = '';
   }
}
countdown();
};
</script>

</head>
<body>
<h2>You can can access the link in <span id="count"></span> seconds <a id="redirect" href="http://google.com/">Google</a></h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create parameterized functions in javascript like this

```
 function countdown(counter) {
    if ( counter != 'undefined' and counter != -1  ) 
    {
       if(counter >= 0) {
        document.getElementById('count').innerHTML = counter--;
        setTimeout(countdown(counter), 500);
       }
    else {
       document.getElementById('redirect').style.display = '';
       }
    }
}
    countdown(<?php echo $wait_level ?>);
```

Comment: you can even pass the html identifiers that would be used in script . Example for the same would be 

function countdown(counter,count_id,redirect_id)
{
}

Comment: There's no such thing as `and` in JavaScript

Comment: Sorry for the mistake. We can use && at the place of 'and'